# logging in to two seperate linode disk images

Tags: linode, disk-image

perhaps I am a bit confused on what a 'disk image' is, but I was under the impression that once I set up multiple disk images in a linode account, they would each act as a distinct server.  I have set up two instances, one running ubuntu 10.04 and one running ubuntu 11.10. whenever I log in via ssh and check the version of Ubuntu (by running `cat /etc/issue`) It still says I am on the first one, which is running 10.04. how can I access the second disk image I created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Linode, you can have multiple operating systems installed per Linode(via multiple partition or via disk images), but only 1 may run at a time.

After creating disk images, you can  change your configuration profile to attach them to specific devices when your linode boots up. However, there is much more to configuration profiles than just mapping disk images to devices.